# retornar true o false desde una funcion que esta dentro de otra funcion en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

esta function es para detectar si no hubo errores a la hora de borrar los registros pero la llamo desde otra funcion asi

```
if(!deleteAllSectionsPage(123) )
{
  //alguna accion.
}
```

tengo

```
function deleteAllSectionsPage(idpage)
{
    Section.destroy(
        {
            where : { 
                page_id: idpage,
                status : 1
            }
        }
    ).then(section => {
        return  true 
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return false 
    });

}
```

pero no me retorna el valor booleano que esta en

```
).then(section => {
        return  true 
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return false 
    });
```

La verdad no conozco porque, me hace falta conocimiento en este tipo de situaciones, he estado buscando pero no lo encuentro y estoy perdido en esto. Alguien me puede decir como puedo solucionar esto ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno creo que lo que podrias hacer, es manejarlo de otra forma, porque vas a necesitar retornar una Promesa o Promise.

Necesitas modificar la funcion para retornar el Promise:

```
function deleteAllSectionsPage(idpage)
{
    return Section.destroy(
       {
           where : { 
               page_id: idpage,
               status : 1
           }
       }
    ).then(section => {
        return  true 
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return false 
    });

}
```

luego el if lo tendrias que manejar de otra forma:

```
deleteAllSectionsPage(1).then(function(result) {
     if (result) {
       // Paso
     } else {
       // No Paso    
     }
})
```

> Por motivos de que la consulta al servidor o la consulta http puede tardar algun tiempo tienes que esperar a que esta accion termine para saber que resultado se obtiene de la funcion.

Aquí el problema es que esta lidiando con Acciones Asíncronas, Porque al hacer una consulta http, javascript procesa esta acción en paralelo y sigue ejecutando el código y de estas formas se forman procesos asíncronos, mejorando la eficiencia en ejecucion. Te recomiendo leer mas de las Promesas. Puedes comenzar aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: excelente. Ese era. Gracias

Comment: De Nada, Con mucho gusto